# Are Goku and Vegeta at full power when they face Freezer in chapter 87 of the Dragon Ball Super manga?

Tags: dragon-ball-super, dragon-ball-manga

In Chapter 87 of the Dragon Ball Super Manga,

> Freezer gets a new transformation, and he hits Goku and Vegeta at the same time, apparently making them lose their power ups and transformations

Are Goku and Vegeta at full power when they face Freezer in chapter 87 of the Dragon Ball Super manga?